# Como acessar um elemento de uma Tag

Tags: javascript, html, react

Estou tentando passar para o meu código javascript (ReactJS) a imagem do caminho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no código eu escrevo assim:

```
source={{ uri: this.state.modelo.baner[0].url_img }}
```

E o navegador acusa este erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Provavelmente esse `this.state.modelo` ainda não tem o `baner` defenido... como é que esse `this.state.modelo` está a ser preenchido/atualizado?

Comment: A imagem acima é uma parte do console.log desse This.

Comment: Nas outras tags eu consigo utilizar

Comment: O que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.modelo));`?

Comment: A melhor forma que conheço de verificar a existência de "props" e "states" após renderizado, é com a extensão [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=pt-BR).